# Any way to interact between node.js and python

Tags: python, pi-3, hardware

Any way to interact between node.js and python.
I wrote a IoT dashboard using Node.js, then want to add a 1602 LCD screen to Raspberry Pi using python, so any way to interact between python and node.js?

Comment: You can execute a Python script from Node.js like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450534/how-to-call-python-function-from-nodejs/23452742#23452742). However, I would just use the Node.js script to handle everything.

Comment: Noted! I execute the python using node.js now, but how can I reply the input from python using Node.js

Comment: Take a closer look at the answer in the link. It shows how to send data both ways.

Comment: Another possibility would be to use some sort of messaging library. `ZeroMQ` has bindings for both python and node.

Answer (score 0):

**Non Real-Time - Simple way**

I always found it much easier to use an intermediary local file between any two different software, especially with systems that are not very complicated in nature and not very time sensitive in execution.

Example: (myNodeJS.js interacting with myPython.py using myJson.json)

myJson.json
{
pymessage: "node do something",
nodeMessage: "python do something",
}

in myNodeJS.js

> > Do something
> > Open myJson, Read what python wants in pyMessage : "nodeDoSomething"
> > Set nodeMessage : "pyDoSomething", then close myJson

in myPython.py

> > Do something
> > Read what node wants in nodeMessage: "pyDoSomething"
> > Open myJson.json, set pyMessage : "nodeDoSomething", then close it

You can also have two files in order to avoid the conflict of opening the same file, e.g. myJson1 and myJson2, one where Python writes the messages and one where node writes messages.

**Real Time - Requires little more work**

In case the application is a real time one where information is sent back-and-forth between node and python then the easiest would be to create a local broker on your RPi, then have Python publish messages to "/topic/python" and have Node subscribed to it. Then also have Node publish to a "/topic/Node" and have Python subscribe to it. Make sure that both send a unified JSON formatted message (or similar) so you're working with one type of parsing and minimize overhead.

There are other more complex ways, but for your application this should work. Good luck.

Comment: I like that.  I use a similar thing with my data-loggers - in Python I open the file, append a record, then close it.  Then they wait a minimum of a minute to repeat the sequence.  But as with this answer, it is best not to hold files open long.    +1

Comment: Yes, like I said this applies only in some cases, but if needs to be done in real time, then they could communicate over MQTT pub/sub style with JSON payloads.